# How can i make this menu dynamic on wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

I have a static html,css Menu but now i want to make it dynamic using wordpress.So i can set the menu from wordpress Appearance->Menu section
It would be great if any one can help me

Here is the code:

```
<nav>
  <div id='cssmenu'>

    <ul>

       <li><a href='/'><span>Home<br>
          <small class="nosmall">Go Home</small>
       </span></a></li>

       <li><a href='about'><span>About<br>
          <small>Our Overview</small>
       </span></a>      
       </li>



       <li><a href='team/'><span>Our Team<br>
           <small>Meet Us</small>
       </span></a></li>

       <li><a href='contact/'><span>Contact<br>
          <small>Let's Work Together</small>
       </span></a></li>

        <li><a href='articles-publications/'><span>Articles & Publications<br>
          <small>Legal Resources</small>
        </span></a>               
       </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: How about you read the manual https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: Can you please help me? I can not get it at all

Comment: The instructions for doing what you want are in the link I gave you. How about you give it a go. If you cannot, I would suggest you find a freelancer. Any answer to this question would just be providing the same information provided in the link. If you have a more specific question once you have attempted the code, you can come back and post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wp nav menu for dynamic menu in wordpress.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```